# How to visually represent a relation made up of relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

If 
$$R_1 ≡ \{(a,a), (a,b), (b,c),(c,a)\}$$
$$R_2 ≡ \{(a,1), (a,2), (b,3),(c,3)\}$$
$$R_3 ≡ \{(a,1), (a,2), (b,3),(c,3)\}$$

Using set notation and actual lines to connect the pairs, I want to show the relation 
$$R_4 ≡ R_1 R_2 R_3^{-1}$$

I think the set notation would be 
$$R_4 = \{(a,a), (a,b), (a,c),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b)\}$$

And I have no idea how to insert the oval shape think to show the process visually, so if anybody can do that it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualise a binary relation $R$ over a set $A$ as a directed graph $G_R$ whose vertices are the elements of $A$ and whose edges correspond to the elements of the relation: If $(a,b) \in R$, then there is an edge from $a$ to $b$ in $G_R$.

Now use distinct colours for the edges corresponding to the three relations and a fourth colour to represent $R_4$.

Comment: Then to represent the relation in set notation, would I follow the lines from the first values (let's say a) all the way to end value (say b), and then that would be one of the values in $R_4$?

Comment: Remember that there is an inverse relation involved. In this case, follow the edges in the opposite direction.